# JNI: Reading a text file in C code and returning to sdk

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

Im trying to create an android app to read text from a text file using NDK .My C code reads a string into a variable and returns the string variable to java code .But when I run the Android app the string displayed in the TextView appears as symbols like @ followed by some rectangles.What is the format of returning strings from JNI? Check the below code.Can I read a system file without any other permission?What will a printf() statement do?

**Java Code:**

```
package com.example.openfile;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
public native String ndkopenfile();
static{
    System.loadLibrary("mylib");
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    //textView1.setText(ndkopenfile());
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str1;
    Log.d("Click","The button has been clicked to open the file");

    str1=ndkopenfile();

    //setTitle(str1);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(str1);
}

}
```

**C code:**

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_openfile_MainActivity_ndkopenfile
(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
{

    jstring str1[20];
    FILE* fp = fopen("/sdcard/x.txt","w+");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        fgets(str1,20,fp);
        fflush(fp);
        fclose(fp);
        return(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,str1);
    }
    else
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"Error opening file!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you write the file from Java? Or you downloaded it from _another_ computer?

Comment: The `NewStringUTF` call takes UTF-8 text.  Unless you're certain that "x.txt" contains valid UTF-8 data, you should convert it yourself (either according to the charset actually used, or by trivially stomping any non-7-bit-ASCII values).  Note that you can do what you're showing here easily from within Java... using the NDK does not grant you additional permissions.

Comment: @fadden No, `NewStringUTF` takes _modified_ UTF-8 text. It can't take all valid UTF-8 strings. See [Android JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#UTF_8_and_UTF_16_strings). As a better alternative to filtering, just call the `java.lang.String(byte[])` constructor, after copying the string to a `jbyteArray`. That way there'd be no data loss.

Comment: Fair point about MUTF-8 (which, somehow, I always neglect to mention).  I would argue there's still possible data loss with the String constructor -- as the doc says, "The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified."  In any event, I've seen a lot of code try to pass arbitrary 8-bit data (filenames, user input) into `NewStringUTF`, which is why CheckJNI will react vigorously when it sees bad input.

Comment: @fadden On Android, the default character set is Unicode and the default encoding is UTF-8. The Android JVM accounts for that. If there is any doubt about what the a JVM uses as its OS default then call the `java.lang.String(byte[], java.lang.Charset)` constructor.

Comment: Right... so if he's passing (say) ISO-8859-1 strings in, he's going to get bad results whether he uses `NewStringUTF` or the `String` constructor.  Either way, the resulting string won't represent the original, and you've lost data.  (I feel like we're talking past each other.)

Comment: Thank you guys.The String format for my file was a Unicode(UTF-8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_openfile_MainActivity_ndkopenfile
(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
{
        char myStr[20];
        FILE* fp = fopen("/sdcard/x.txt","w+");
        if(fp!=NULL)
        {
            fgets(myStr,20,fp);
            fflush(fp);
            fclose(fp);
            return(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,myStr);
        }
        else
        {
            fclose(fp);
            return(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"Error opening file!");
        }
}
```

This technique works perfectly !!! Tested.

Comment: OMG That did it!
Thank You!
But If you could answer the other question Ill be gratefull!!!

Comment: @user2745435: Which question? Post the link to your question in here i'll try.

Comment: Ive seen some coders put a printf statement in Java native code. Out of curiosity i tried it too ,but nothing happened.

Comment: If the file fails to open, you don't need to close it. The fclose line in the else must be removed. As documentation said fclose NULL result in a segmentation violation

Comment: @Zax I get some issue from above code. Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) code 1, fault addr 0xc in tid 13524.

Comment: @Manoj: I am getting the same. Did u solve the issue?

Comment: The fclose line in the else must be removed!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your definition `jstring str1[20];` need to modify to `char str1[20]`. Because jstring type is defined as a jobject, it's not basic type of char.